# display Multi parents-childs dynamic Diagrams in sharepoint web access

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, chart, visio

We design KMS (Knowledge Management Systems) with SharePoint that everything is OK but we need to Display relations between entities,Documents and etc. in Web access.

[image: ajax tree example javascript library for building tree-node hierarchy Publish Visio drawings to a SharePoint site Sample MindMap diagrams for SharePoint Taxonomies]

my question about solutions: (please help me to deside better choice) or recommend ...

1-visio

or

2-templates (HTML,JAVA,JSON, Webpart)

> 1-we can [design and develop lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/26319/5170) and UIs for data entry the get
>   information from users , but we don't know that Did have [Visio services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio-help/save-diagrams-to-sharepoint-as-web-drawings-HA010357073.aspx) capacities for use that to
>   update visualize webpart? Is there any way to create/update Visio
>   documents by programming?
>
> 2-Is there any webpart or HTML or [Java](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) or another templates that
>   we generate that codes with programming in that web part?or is this hard to show [JSONs](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html)
>   in SharePoint Webparts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a javascript API for Visio but it does not allow you to insert new objects.  Not sure about a real code solution.
2. JSON can certainly be used.  Even without real code, I usually create a script which I can either insert directly into a page or link via a Content Editor web part.

The main limitation I have experienced with Visio is the size of the file quickly increases if you have a lot of objects.

Comment: How to reduce the size of a Visio drawing file in Visio http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio-help/reduce-the-size-of-a-visio-file-HA010082918.aspx

Comment: did you try these: Adding Shapes to a New Visio Document http://stackoverflow.com/q/9469739/308578 or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160744.aspx

Comment: Not me - I steer clear of the real dev stuff - jQuery is my limit :)